# sorting a PERL array by date on ASCII

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

What I need to do is wrote a script that will read in a list of directories
and then sort them and the last directory will be "poped" off.

my $last_one = pop @sorted;

Then that last directory is going to be removed - with a system("rm- rf $last_one) or 
remove_tree($last_one).

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/perl
 2  use strict;
 3  use warnings;
 4
 5  my $dir_to_process = "/production/log/fo/archive/";
 6  opendir DH, $dir_to_process or die "Sorry, this is not going to work out $!";
 7
 8  while (my $name = readdir DH) {
 9       next if $name =~ /^\./;
10       push(my @unsorted,$name) ;
11       my @sorted_dir = sort @unsorted;
12       foreach my $sorted (@sorted_dir) {
13       print "$sorted\n";
14       sleep 1 ;
15       }
16
17  }
```

However I am having alot of trouble sorting the directories - they are written by this format. 
This is the actual output.

```
2013Nov12
2013Sep14
2013Jul15
2013Jan20
2013Sep11
2013May31
2013Jul04
2012Dec09
2013Oct12
2013Oct09
2012Dec27
2013Nov28
2013Mar24
2013Jun06
2013Jun25
```

Comment: You say "sorting by ASCII" in your title but I assume what you really want is to sort by date (i.e. oldest to newest or vice versa)?

Comment: Sorting makes no sense if you just want to find the oldest.

Comment: the problem is that it is sorting by ascii, and not by date - yes what i need is the oldest dated directory.

Answer (score 5):

Let's presume the existence of a function `convert_date` that converts your date to the YYYYMMDD format. If you had a that, a simple string comparison would find the oldest.

```
my ($oldest) =
   sort { convert_date($a) cmp convert_date($b) }
   @dirs;
```

Faster:

```
my ($oldest) =
   map $_->[0],
   sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
   map [ $_, convert_date($_) ],
   @dirs;
```

Fastest:

```
my ($oldest) =
   map substr($_, 8),
   sort
   map convert_date($_) . $_,
   @dirs;
```

---

But sorting (O(N log N)) is a wasteful way of finding one element (O(N)).

```
my $oldest = $dirs[0];
for (@dirs) {
   $oldest = $_ if convert_date($_) lt $oldest;
}
```

Faster?

```
use List::Util qw( minstr );
my $oldest = substr(minstr( map { convert_date($_) . $_ } @dirs ), 8);
```

---

Now, all that's left is writing `convert_date`.

```
use Carp qw( croak );

my %month_num_by_en_name = (
   Jan => 1,  Feb =>  2,  Mar =>  3,  Apr =>  4,
   May => 5,  Jun =>  6,  Jul =>  7,  Aug =>  8,
   Sep => 9,  Oct => 10,  Nov => 11,  Dec => 12,
);


sub convert_date {
   my ($date) = @_;

   my ($y,$m,$d) = $date =~ m/^(\d{4})(\w{3})(\d{2})\z/
      or croak("Invalid input");

   $m = $month_num_by_en_name{$m}
      or croak("Invalid input");

   return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", $y,$m,$d);
}
```

You could also use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime). This makes it easier to support other languages.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y%b%d',
   locale   => 'en_US',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

sub convert_date {
   my ($date) = @_;
   return $format->parse_datetime($date)->strftime('%Y%m%d');
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. Do you mind me asking why you use `Carp`? Is it out of habit or is there a gain (always talking about the OP's scenario)?

Comment: @foibs, Because Carp provides `croak`, which is appropriate here.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant how is `croak` more appropriate than `die`. Thanks

Comment: It's usually best to use `croak`/`carp` instead of `die`/`warn` in library code. Because your user (by which I mean the programmer who is using your library) doesn't care where in your code the error is. He cares where he called your function with an invalid parameter.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks. It is out of habit then, because here we're talking about a simple script, neither a library, nor a module. It is a good habit I may add.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a function to convert your directory names to dates (splitting the date info into things you can sort: Year, Month, Day).

Here's an example

```
sub parsedate {
  my $name = shift;
  my %months = ( 'Jan'=> 1, 'Feb' => 2, 'Mar' => 3, 'Apr' => 4,
    'May'=> 5, 'Jun' => 6, 'Jul' => 7, 'Aug' => 8,
    'Sep'=> 9, 'Oct' => 10, 'Nov' => 11, 'Dec' => 12 );

  my ($y,$m,$d);
  $name =~ m/^(\d{4})(\w{3})(\d{2})$/ 
    and ($y,$m,$d) = ($1,$months{$2},$3)
    or die "file name $name doesn't match";

  return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d",$y,$m,$d);
}
```

Now you can just sort them using your new sub `parsedate`.

```
my @sorted_dir = sort {parsedate($a) <=> parsedate($b)} @unsorted;
```

Answer (score 2):

sort() accepts code block where you can define your own sorting algorithm. Just convert your dir names to timestamp and you should go. This will be smth like
`sort { date2stamp($a) <=> date2stamp($b) } @unsorted`
And inside date2stamp sub use POSIX::mktime() to create right timestamp for date string.

Answer (score 2):

convert the month name to a number, then make a number out of the y m d
Then sort the numbers numerically
The "schwartzian transform" is used to attach the numbers to the filenames

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
#
use warnings;
use strict;

my %monthval=qw(Jan 01 Feb 02 Mar 03 Apr 04 May 05 Jun 06 Jul 07 Aug 08 Sep 09 O
ct 10 Nov 11 Dec 12);


my @in=qw(2013Nov12
2013Sep14
2013Jul15
2013Jan20
2013Sep11
2013May31
2013Jul04
2012Dec09
2013Oct12
2013Oct09
2012Dec27
2013Nov28
2013Mar24
2013Jun06
2013Jun25);

my @sorted = map{$_->[0]} sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}  map { my ($y,$m,$d)=/(\d{
4})(\w{3})(\d{2})/; [$_,"$y".$monthval{$m}."$d"]} @in;

foreach my $name (@sorted) {
  print "$name\n";
}
```